# Is an Interface considered a parent of a class that implements it?

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I've got a framework here that uses an object to maintain state between other objects as they interact with it. I was hoping that the objects that interact with the state ("Actions") could generically accept a type of interface, which the State object would implement, but I'm having trouble making this work.

I want to define the framework object itself in terms of a specific state implementation (or interface), and be able to add Actions to it, as long as they accept the defined state, either directly or through an interface that the state implements.

As I understand it, the `<? super S>` definition means "some type that is a parent of S", but I am not sure that an Interface that is implemented by S fits this description, as it's not exactly a parent class.

Here's an example (not exactly compiling code):

```
Class Framework<State> {
    addAction(Action<? super State> a) {} // adds to a list of actions to be run

    run(State s) {
        for(Action<? super State> a : actions) {
            a.perform(s);
        }
    }
}

Interface IState1 {}

Interface IState2 {}

Interface Action<State> {
    public void perform(State s);
}

Class Action1 implements Action<IState1> {}

Class Action2 implements Action<IState2> {}

Class CombinedState implements IState1, IState2 {}

public static void run() {
    Framework<CombinedState> f = new Framework<CombinedState>();

    // add is expecting Action<? super CombinedState> but getting Action<IState1>
    f.add(new Action1()); // This doesn't seem to work
    f.add(new Action2());

    f.run(new CombinedState());
}
```

For the purposes of generics, do Interfaces count as parent classes?  Is there any way to implement this that doesn't require reflection?

Comment: Do you want to accept objects that extends from the State interface ?

Comment: I want to accept Actions that are able to use the CombinedState, either directly or because CombinedState implements an interface that they accept.

Comment: Well, your code would compile, if: 1) you wrote `class` and `interface` with lowercase first-letter; 2) the class `Framework` had an `add()` method (actually has `addAction()`)

Comment: What is `State` in this code?Is this like saying `T` or is `State` an interface defined somewhere?Please put actual code

Comment: It's exactly like saying 'T', but with a more descriptive type variable name.

@Natix: turns out that was exactly the problem :)

Comment: And to answer your question: Yes, an interface IS a super type of the classes that implement it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

class State{}

class Framework<State> 
{
    public ArrayList< Action< ? super State > >actions = new ArrayList< Action< ?super State > >();

    void add(Action<? super State> a) {

        actions.add(a);

    } 

    void doRun(State s) {
        for(Action<? super State> a : actions) {
            a.perform(s);
        }
    }
}

interface IState1 {}

interface IState2 {}

interface Action<State> {
    public void perform(State s);
}

class Action1 implements Action<IState1> {
    public void perform( IState1 s )
    {
        System.out.println("Do something 1");
    }
}

class Action2 implements Action<IState2> {

    public void perform( IState2 s )
    {
        System.out.println("Do something 2");
    }   
}

class CombinedState implements IState1, IState2 {}

class Untitled {
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
         Framework<CombinedState> f = new Framework<CombinedState>();

            // add is expecting Action<? super CombinedState> but getting Action<IState1>
            f.add(new Action1()); // This doesn't seem to work
            f.add(new Action2());

            f.doRun(new CombinedState());
    }
}
```

This runs in CodeRunner on OSX.

Comment: You defined State as a class though. Is that necessary?

Comment: @Bracket: I also think that it isn't necessary. In `Framework<State>`, the `State` is just a type parameter (the same as `T`).

Comment: Oh do I feel stupid. I was using "add" instead of "addAction" in my code, which is what I actually defined. I feel embarrassed now that I took it this far for a simple typo.  But seeing that it works for you made me realize my mistake!